# Is there a way to have use v lookup or a different formula with duplicate lookup but different row values?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have two worksheets. The first worksheet has all the data that I am working with (the first table shown). The second worksheet contains information I want to have pulled from the first worksheet (table 3 shown).

I am currently given the "outcome" in worksheet two and I want to pull the type and cost from worksheet one. Since there are duplicates in my outcome, the vlookup I use only gives the first row that contains the outcome. Table 2 shows how it looks with the vlookup.
I would like it to look like table 3, with the same outcome but with both the type listed and the cost as well.

Thank you for your help.

Table 1

| Outcome | Type | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | labor | 45 |
| b | material | 23 |
| b | labor | 43 |
| c | material | 78 |
| c | labor | 98 |
| d | material | 12 |
| e | material | 45 |
| e | labor | 78 |

Table 2

| Outcome | Type | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | labor | 45 |
| c | material | 78 |
| c | material | 78 |
| d | material | 12 |
| e | material | 45 |
| e | material | 45 |

Table3

| Outcome | Type | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | labor | 45 |
| c | material | 78 |
| c | labor | 98 |
| d | material | 12 |
| e | material | 45 |
| e | labor | 78 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array formula：

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100=$A2,ROW($1:$100)),COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! There are other columns in my data as well, I was wondering is there a way to select certain columns from the data worksheet instead of all of them?

Comment: What is the basis for selecting certain columns？If it's headline, OFFSET can be used

Comment: Ahh nevermind, I ended up adjusting the columns and it worked out. Thank you!